# Pong Paddle bottom doesn't move up when UP key is pressed

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a pong game but my pong paddle isn't moving up properly for some reason.

When I hit the DOWN arrow key it moves down just fine. But when I hit the UP arrow key the whole paddle just get's longer upwards... If i resize the window the paddle returns to it's normal length at that position. If i press UP key it again continues to extend upwards.

I don't think its my code logic but something about clearing the previously drawn paddle... here's my code,

Code for Paddle:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Paddle extends JPanel {

    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;

    Paddle(){
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.height = 40;
        this.width = 10;
    }

    Paddle(int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void moveDown(){
        this.y += 3;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("h: " + height + " x: " + x + " y: " + y + " getW: " + getWidth() + " getH: " + getHeight());
    }

    public void moveUp(){
        this.y -= 3;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("h: " + height + " x: " + x + " y: " + y + " getW: " + getWidth() + " getH: " + getHeight());
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

}
```

Code for Whole Game:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Pong extends JFrame {

    Pong() {
        final Paddle p1Paddle = new Paddle();

        Paddle p2Paddle = new Paddle();
        p1Paddle.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.keyPressed(arg0);

                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                        p1Paddle.moveDown();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                        p1Paddle.moveUp();
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("please press up or down");
                }

            }
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(p1Paddle, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //only focused components can recieve key events...
        p1Paddle.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new Pong();
        frame.setTitle("Pong");
        frame.setSize(650, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Any help on this issue or general code advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have clearRect(0,0,650,300) hard coded?

Comment: i want to clear the whole window and make sure i haven't missed any part of the paddle... but paddle is not affected for some reason.

Comment: Why are you changing the height every time you moveUp and moveDown?

Comment: could it be bkz i'm drawing on a jpanel.. and the size of the jpanel isn't necessarily the size of the overall window?

Comment: bkz if i don't update the height and width the paddle gets shorter or longer as i change the x and y position; i need to keep the paddle at a static height

Comment: when i don't change the height, the paddle gets smaller (smushes into itself) when i press the down key and longer when i press the up key. when i update the height along with the y value the paddle stays at the same length visually but it has a larger height value (internally)... not sure why this is happening..

Comment: Could you please make a working example? When making your Paddle a JComponent, adding it to a JFrame and moving the key listener to the JFrame, then the paddle repaints fine without changing the height (as expected). Also, then the clearing rect is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hard to tell from the code snippet, but, KeyListeners aren't very reliable.  If the key stroke is been consumed (by the UI and underlying implementation) you may not be notified.

Try looking at InputMap and ActionMap instead.

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
ActionMap am = getActionMap();

KeyStroke downKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0);
KeyStroke upKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0);

im.put(downKey, "Action.down");
im.put(upKey, "Action.up");

am.put("Action.down", new DownAction());
am.put("Action.up", new UpAction());
```

And see where it takes you...

**Update:**
Ahh, it's so obvious now, you've overridden the x/y width/height methods of the panel expecting the layout manager to use them to layout out the component, but not really providing a layout manager who knows how to deal with it.

BorderLayout does not care about you "size" or "position" requirements, it will override them with what it thinks you component should be.

What you want to do is use an absolute layout manager instead (null).  Also, you DON'T want to implement the X/Y, width/height management, as this is already taken care for you.

So.

In the Pong class.  Change the layout manager from BorderLayout to null (also update the add(paddle) method to remove the BorderLayout reference, not required, but removes confusion).

In the Paddle class, remove all references to the x/y, width/height, you don't need them.  Instead use setBounds/setLocation.

```
public class Paddle extends JPanel {

Paddle(){

        this(0, 0, 20, 40);

}

Paddle(int x, int y, int width, int height){

        setBounds(x, y, width, height);

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    // The graphics context has already been translated to x/y for use,
    // so we don't need to care about it
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public void moveDown(){

        setLocation(getX(), getY() + 3);

}

public void moveUp(){

        setLocation(getX(), getY() - 3);

}
```

}

And viola, it works.

Comment: I don't have a problem with receiving the keyboard keys. I just don't know why the paddle drawing isn't rendering properly. I have attached all of my code in the original question. Let me know if you see anything wrong. Thanks.

Comment: wow! Thanks, that was perfect. I have some questions so I can understand this better. How come in the 1st constructor for paddle you use "this(0,0,20,40)" but in the other you use set bounds. why not "this(x,y,width,height)" and vice versa -  just trying to understand the reason for the inconsistency. and If i understand this right, the paddle is currently floating about on the "absolute" layout, so if i want to do collision detection. I would have to go back to my pong class. or make a 'table' jpanel class where the paddle and ball are free to float around at... Thanks a bunch for  your help

Comment: nevermind the constructor question. I get it now! instead of typing setbounds twice you call the 2nd constructor from the 1st constructor.!!... java noob here, oopsies..